How can I delete a file in a Yeoman generator without prompting for confirmation in the terminal?
I'm working on a Yeoman generator, and I need to delete some files programmatically without prompting for confirmation in the terminal. Currently, when I use this.fs.delete(${rootDestinationPath}/${filePath});`, it prompts the user to confirm deletion with "ynarxdeiH" on terminal. Is there a way to bypass this confirmation prompt and delete the file directly without user input?
Here's the code snippet where I'm encountering this issue:
this.fs.delete(`${rootDestinationPath}/${filePath}`);

Any insights or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
I have tried to find options to pass to the function  'delete' to force deletion without requiring confirmation.

Yeoman generators typically don't have a built-in function for deleting files without confirmation. However, you can achieve this functionality using the underlying file system manipulation libraries:
const fs = require('fs');
const filePathToDelete = 'path/to/file.txt';

try {
  fs.unlinkSync(filePathToDelete);
  console.log(`File deleted: ${filePathToDelete}`);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`Error deleting file: ${err}`);
}

